# ADFS Passive Request = "There are no registered protocol handlers"

Tags: adfs, adfs3.0, windows-server-2016

Im trying to configure `ADFS` to work as a `Claim Provider` (I suppose AD will be the `identity provider` in this case).

Just for simple testing, ive tried the following on `windows server 2016` machine:

1) Setup AD and domain = `t1.testdom` (Its working cause im actually able to login with the domain)

2) Setup DNS. Added a host (A) for adfs as `fs.t1.testdom`

3) selfsigned certificate (https://technet.microsoft.com/library/hh848633):

```
powershell> New-SelfSignedCertificate -DnsName "*.t1.testdom"
```

4) created a dedicated service account for gMSA

5) setup ADFS.

Server name set as `fs.t1.testdom`

service>authentication method is enabled as `form authentication`

6) Also fixed the SPN via powershell to make sure all needed SPNs are there and given to the right user account and that no duplicates are found

--

However, when I try to access the login page on browser via `https://fs.t1.testdom/adfs/ls` I get the error. The log on server manager says the following:

```
`There are no registered protocol handlers on path /adfs/ls to process the incoming request`
```

So is there a way to reach at least the login screen? So I can move on to the next error.

---

this is what I get on the `/ls` screen:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Finally found the solution after a week of google, tries, server rebuilds etc!

(This guru answered it in a blink and no one knew it!
https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/28994182/ADFS-Passive-Request-There-are-no-registered-protocol-handlers.html)

The IdP-Initiated SSO page (https://fs.t1.testdom/adfs/ls/idpinitiatedsignon.aspx). Note that if you are using Server 2016, this endpoint is **disabled by default** and you need to enable it first via the AD FS console or

```
Set-AdfsProperties -EnableIdPInitiatedSignonPage $true
```

--

My question is, if this endpoint is disabled, why isnt it listed in the endpoints section of ADFS Management console?!!